# Newbie Help - Trouble with NPN resistor

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFTnCC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:  I have boiled the problem down to it's simplest component. I need to use the Emitter of a PNP (2N3906) to be the base of a NPN (2N2222) to light an LED.

I have a circuit I'm trying to get to work.  Here is the relevant part.

The battery is actually an at 11.1v (DC power supply).  I know in this image the PNP is kind of pointless, but it's necessary for the overall project. If this isn't enough info I'll draw up the whole circuit, but I think this is the relevant part.

So when I push the button I need an LED to go light up from receiving the hot end of 5v.  I need the same button to send a ground signal to a sound trigger (represented here by a Red LED).  The blue light poriton of this works great, but for some reason the NPN is ALWAYS completing the circuit to the Red LED.  I'm hoping to have it only complete the circuit to the LED when the button is engaged.
What am I doing wrong? 
The NPN is a 2222
The PNP is a 3906

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMCzOs.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. OP's circuit redrawn in conventional manner reading from left to right with current flow from top to bottom.*

Comment: *hot end of 5v* - there is no 5V in the circuit.

Comment: Please draw the circuit using the schematics editor button while editing question..If not draw nicely on a paper and attach the pic..

Comment: You're right, misspoke.  There is no 5v in this circuit.  The LED portion works as needed.  I'm curious why the Emitter and Collector complete the ground circuit on the NPN regardless of the condition of the base. Is it the wrong value transistor? Do I need a resistor between the two transistors?

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: I tried to output the schematic but fritzing made it a jumbled mess.  I"m kind of new to this so schematic view is very difficult for me.

Comment: @joeyarkenstat02 ***Use the schematic editor button*** that exists when you are editing your question. If you designed the schematic, you should be perfectly able to use a new editor to replicate your design. You should NOT need to force fritzing to produce one for you. (Unless you have no clues at all about schematics and you copied this fritzing thing from somewhere else.)

Comment: @joeyarkenstat02 Also, describe what you mean by "sound trigger." I know you are representing it as an LED. But I don't think we care about that, because it assumes that you know enough to say that it is a valid "emulator" of what you really need. Better to just spill it and say what it actually is. Finally, I gather you want BOTH an LED lit up AND ALSO a sound trigger to occur simultaneously with the pressing of the button. True?

Comment: It's an Adafruit Mini Soundboard.  When one of the pins goes to ground it triggers the board to play the WAV file.  I'm making a toy gun, the button is a trigger that will light up and play the sound.  Yes, both at the same time.

Comment: Q2 CE reversed ....  change 10K to 1K for both LEDs

Comment: @joey: I've redrawn your schematic (as Figure 3) so you can see more clearly.

Comment: Sigh. Which LED is the red LED? We're not mind readers. Just a tip - if you label a component on the schematic, refer to that label in your question. So your choice is D1 or D2.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  I deleted the image that showed the LEDs, sorry.  I know your'e not mind readers.  I switched it over to a simpler schematic which only has 1 LED.

Comment: Then get rid of the unused schematic! Exorcise it or delete it or whatever, but get rid of it. It just makes your question hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you have mind, but from your description you could just use one switch and two resistors and no transistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyITm3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even if you put the PNP in there for some reason, R2+D1 and R3+D2 could be put in parallel and lose the NPN.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPXXnm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this what you had in mind?  External switch low and LED on at the same time with common gnd.

Comment: Hi Tony.  Yes this is what I meant, but this doesn't use the PNP.  I know the circuit I put up doesn't need it,  so I think I dug myself a hole trying to not have to draw out everything.  I might delete this thread and make a different one wiht all the components and everything> I'm just very new to this schematic drawing and its very confusing for me.

Comment: This is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Circuit to swith the high side of D2 and the low side of D1 from a single button press.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ExAg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the B-E junction of a bipolar transistor is like a diode and you need something to limit the current else the transistor will be damaged. here R1 limit the current Q1 and R4 limits the current to Q2